# How to call a class without making it static

Tags: java

Im trying to call the class Player, but it asks me to change a few methods to static, thus creating 800 warnings and breaking my whole server.
Is the only solution is to fix the 800 warnings? (Telling me to access the method in a static way?

A few things to note:
I need to do it without putting Player player in the method like:
public void methodname(Player player) {
And do it without using a constructor, as the constructor I already have cannot be applied to the code I am trying to do.

The whole method is this

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    //args = new String[] { "true", "false", "true" };
    if (args.length != 3) {
        System.err.println("USE: guimode(boolean) debug(boolean) hosted");
        return;
    }
    Config.HOSTED = Boolean.parseBoolean(args[2]);
    Config.DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean(args[1]);
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Logger.log("Launcher", "Initiating Cache...");
    Cache.init();
    ItemEquipIds.init();
    Huffman.init();
    Logger.log("Launcher", "Initiating Data Files...");
    IPBanL.init();
    PkRank.init();
    TeleportLocations.initTeleportLocations();
    DTRank.init();
    MapContainersXteas.init();
    MapAreas.init();
    ObjectSpawns.init();
    NPCSpawns.init();
    NPCCombatDefinitionsL.init();
    NPCBonuses.init();
    NPCDrops.init();
    ItemExamines.init();
    ItemBonuses.init();
    ShopsHandler.init();
    NPCDefinitions.getNPCDefinitions(20);
    Logger.log("Launcher", "Initiating Fishing Spots...");
    FishingSpotsHandler.init();
    Logger.log("Launcher", "Initiating NPC Combat Scripts...");
    CombatScriptsHandler.init();
    Logger.log("Launcher", "Initiating Dialogues...");
    DialogueHandler.init();
    Logger.log("Launcher", "Initiating Controlers...");
    ControlerHandler.init();
    Logger.log("Launcher", "Initiating Cutscenes...");
    CutscenesHandler.init();
    Logger.log("Launcher", "Initiating Friend Chats Manager...");
    FriendChatsManager.init();
    Logger.log("Launcher", "Initiating Cores Manager...");
    CoresManager.init();
    Logger.log("Launcher", "Initiating World...");
    World.init();
    Logger.log("Launcher", "Initiating Region Builder...");
    RegionBuilder.init();
    Logger.log("Launcher", "Initiating Server Channel Handler...");
    NPCSpawner.spawnNPCS();
    try {
        ServerChannelHandler.init();
    } catch (ChannelException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Logger.log("Launcher",
                "Failed Initiating Server Channel Handler. Shutting down...");
        System.exit(1);
        return;
    }
    // Logger.log("Launcher", "Initiating Server Manager...");
    // ServerManager.main(null);
    System.err.println("Server took "
            + (System.currentTimeMillis() - currentTime)
            + " miliseconds to start up.");
    addAccountsSavingTask();
    addCleanMemoryTask();
    for ( ;; )
    {
       try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            player.sendMessage("[Server Message]: Remember to vote!");
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            player.sendMessage("[<img=1>Server Message<img=1>]: Donate to Lubricant and ONLY Lubricant!");
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
    }
}
```

Also note I cannot change my constructor player, or have a new constructor with nothing initiated in it (I.E public Player { } )
Here is my player constructor:

public class Player extends Entity {

```
public Player(String password) {
    super(Config.START_PLAYER_LOCATION);
    trampAmount = 1;
    setHitpoints(100);
    this.password = password;
    appearence = new Appearence();
    inventory = new Inventory();
    equipment = new Equipment();
    skills = new Skills();
    combatDefinitions = new CombatDefinitions();
    prayer = new Prayer();
    bank = new Bank();
    controlerManager = new ControlerManager();
    musicsManager = new MusicsManager();
    emotesManager = new EmotesManager();
    friendsIgnores = new FriendsIgnores();
    dominionTower = new DominionTower();
    charges = new ChargesManager();
    runEnergy = 100;
    allowChatEffects = true;
    mouseButtons = true;
    pouches = new int[4];
    killedBarrowBrothers = new boolean[6];
    SkillCapeCustomizer.resetSkillCapes(this);
}
```

Comment: Where exactly you are using Player player = new Player("password"); ?

Comment: What do you mean by call the class Player? You cannot call a class, only methods. Could you give clearer code that illustrates the problem? The above code contains a lot of code that doesn't seem to be related to the actual problem. Also it is missing parts like the declaration and initialization of player.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about, how you made an object of Player class inside the class that has the main() method. Since you are creating object outside the scope of the main method, which being static in nature, it is telling you that you cannot use non-static variable from a static context. So for this you can add the static keyword to your Player variable, to make it work. Do check the code snippet, and check, can that be used too in your case too.

```
public class StaticVariable
{
    static One one = new One("New Password"); // This is what I mean, you can do.

    public static void main(String... args)
    {       
        StaticVariable.one.callMe(); // That's how you will call your methods now.
    }
}

class One
{
    String password;

    public One(String p)
    {
        password = p;
    }

    public void callMe()
    {
        System.out.println("I am callMe method of class One.");
        System.out.println(password);
    }
}
```

Else you have to provide the good [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), of the class that has the main method.